# How do you display a WMI Collection to a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wmi

I have just started WPF and am a bit lost.

#### XAML Code:

```
<DataGrid  Name="dgResults" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
</DataGrid>
```

#### C# Code:

```
private void GetServices(string strComputer)
{
     ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + strComputer + @"\root\cimv2");
     SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Select * From Win32_Service");
     ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
     ManagementObjectCollection services = searcher.Get();
     dgResults.ItemsSource = services;
}
```

I was expecting that the WMI Win32_Service query would show the WMI properties as the headers and each object in the returned collection would be displayed as a row.  But it is showing the ManagementObjectCollection properties.  Is there a way to convert it and still allow all properties to be accessible?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This code shows `ManagementObject` properties. "Properties" here means CLR properties, not the WMI properties (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementbaseobject.properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also, it's a bad idea to create WMI objects and forget them - `ManagementObjectSearcher`, `ManagementObjectCollection` and every `ManagementBaseObject`, which will be enumerated via collection, are `IDisposable` and must be disposed.

Comment: Good catch Dennis.  I am not used to c# as of yet.  I usually script my applications in vbs, batch.  I will either adopt your using statements which have the dispose called by the compiler or manually call the dispose method inside the try or finally blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky thing.

First, since you don't want to display CLR properties of `ManagementBaseObject` instances, you have to use type descriptors concept to tell the binding engine, that you have custom bunch of properties. Here's descendants of [`CustomTypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.customtypedescriptor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll need:

```
internal sealed class ManagementObjectPropertDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private readonly PropertyData propertyData;

    public ManagementObjectPropertDescriptor(PropertyData propertyData)
        : base(propertyData.Name, null)
    {
        this.propertyData = propertyData;
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return typeof(ManagementObjectTypeDescriptor); }
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return propertyData.Value;
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return propertyData.Value != null ? propertyData.Value.GetType() : typeof(object); }
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public sealed class ManagementObjectTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private PropertyData[] managementObjectProperties;

    public ManagementObjectTypeDescriptor(ManagementBaseObject source)
    {
        this.managementObjectProperties = source
            .Properties
            .Cast<PropertyData>()
            .ToArray();
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(managementObjectProperties
            .Select(p => new ManagementObjectPropertDescriptor(p))
            .ToArray());
    }
}
```

For simplicity properties are made read-only.
Next, you need to turn `ManagementObjectCollection` into collection of `ManagementObjectTypeDescriptor`:

```
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + strComputer + @"\root\cimv2");
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Select * From Win32_Service");

        var typeDescriptors = new ObservableCollection<ManagementObjectTypeDescriptor>();

        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            using (var managementObjects = searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementBaseObject managementObject in managementObjects)
                {
                    using (managementObject)
                    {
                        typeDescriptors.Add(new ManagementObjectTypeDescriptor(managementObject));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dgResults.ItemsSource = new ArrayList(typeDescriptors);
```

Note, that `ItemsSource` is a non-generic implementation of `IList`. The `DataGrid` has a buggy, from my point, behavior here: if you'll set a generic `IList<ManagementObjectTypeDescriptor>` as the items source, `DG` will just ignore the fact of inheritance from `CustomTypeDescriptor`, and you'll see no columns in the grid at all. At the same time, non-generic `IList` works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure, that these are DG columns, may be, you're applying any custom style? In empty WPF application with defaults styles I have 1st column "AcceptPause", and last column "WaitHint". There are no any empty columns.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the style and the auto fill property of the DataGrid.  I am only displaying 2 columns by modifying SelectQuery.  The rest are empty space with column/row borders that just appear to be another column.  Looks like I need to modify my XAML parameters to properly size the Width automatically and AutoSize to contents.  I am assuming that interacting with the ArrayList(typeDescriptors) array will let me append custom columns of my own like row indexes?

Comment: @Mark: that's right, just modify `GetProperties` to return appropriate `PropertyDescriptor` descendant, and you'll get custom property and respective column in DG.